# Why am I getting first response as an empty array in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below I am trying to fetch data and use the onInputValue function in my other component called Search. It's working fine after first attempt, but I am getting an empty array in my initial button click

```
const App = () => {
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);


    const onInputValue = async (input) => {
        
        const { data } = await nasa.get('/search', {
            params: {
                q: input,
            },
        });
        if(!results) {
            return;
        }
        setResults(data.collection.items);
        console.log(results);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <Search onInputValue={onInputValue} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';

const Search = ({ onInputValue }) => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    return (
        <div className='input-group mb-3'>
            <input
                type='text'
                className='form-control'
                placeholder='To infinity and beyond!'
                onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
            />
            <div className='input-group-append'>
                <button
                    onClick={() => {onInputValue(input)}}
                    className='btn btn-outline-secondary'
                    type='button'
                >
                    <i className='fas fa-rocket'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Search;
```

Below is the result I get.
[image]

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

setResults is asynchronous if you want to check results you can use useEffect

```
const App = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(results);
  }, [results])

  const onInputValue = async (input) => {
    const {data} = await nasa.get('/search', {
      params: {
        q: input,
      },
    });
    if (!results) {
      return;
    }
    setResults(data.collection.items);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Search onInputValue={onInputValue} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to asynchronous nature of `setResults` function - after calling it, the updated value of `results` will be available on the next component render - in your example you're logging in to console immediately after invoking `setResults`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the `setResults` is batched and therefore move to the next line.

See `useState` batch updates.

Also

`if(!results) { return; }`

Is a bit suspect. `![] === false` and `!['someValue'] === false`